# reading a file to use within an express route

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, scope

I am trying to implement a search functionality for my app. I have an express route to get incoming search terms.

Here is the entirety of my router file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var searchutil = require('../utils/searchhandler');

router.use( bodyParser.json() );
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

router.post('/api/search', (req, res, next) => {
  var term = req.body.searchTerm;
  console.log(term);
  searchutil();
  res.json({test: 'post received'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

And here is my searchhandler file which is being including in my router:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var findResults = function() {
  var items = fs.readFile('./server/assets/items.json', 'utf8', (err, data) =>{
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    return JSON.parse(data);
  });
}

module.exports = findResults;
```

This is all working just fine and dandy. it basically just prints out the contents of `'./server/assets/items.json'` on the server when a post request route of `'/api/search'` is hit. The question I had was about using the json file within my router file. Say my router file was:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');

var items = fs.readFile('./server/assets/items.json', 'utf8', (err, data) =>{
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(JSON.parse(data));
  return JSON.parse(data);
});

router.use( bodyParser.json() );
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

router.post('/api/search', (req, res, next) => {
  var term = req.body.searchTerm;
  console.log(term);
  console.log(items);
  res.json({test: 'post received'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

So now my router file is getting the file asset and trying to print it out within my `router.post('/api/search', ...);` function. The problem that occurs is that when it attempts to print it in that function `items` appears to be `undefined`, but the print from within the `fs.readFile();` correctly logs the contents of the file. I think this is some sort of scope issue I am running into with JS, but I am not sure how to explain it to myself so I thought I'd ask it here why it is working one way, but not the other.

Comment: items is set asynchronously so its value isn't set at the time it is printed

Comment: you could use a promise and wait for items to be set though

Comment: @pwilmot - that is what I thought, but in the 2nd version of my router file it prints it within the readFile function on the `console.log(JSON.parse(data));` before the `console.log(items);` within the post function is called. If it successfully printed in the readFile function shouldn't it already be set for the post function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a callback:

```
var getItems = function(cb) { 
  fs.readFile('./server/assets/items.json', 'utf8', (err, data) {
     if (err) cb({error: err});
     console.log(JSON.parse(data));
     cb({items: JSON.parse(data)});
  });
};
```

And then change the route to:

```
router.post('/api/search', (req, res, next) => {
  var term = req.body.searchTerm;
  console.log(term);
  getItems(function (cb) {
     if (!cb.error) {
        console.log(cb.items);
        res.json({test: 'post received'});
     }
  });
});
```